# Call C# method in JavaScript (in Chrome extension)

Tags: javascript, c#, methods, google-chrome-extension

I have made a method getting HTML file as parameter in C# project.
Recently making a Chrome extension I need to reuse the C# method that I have made.
All I need is a way to give HTML source get by a Chrome extension to the C# method that I have made.
There's no need server or anything. All process occurs in local drive.
Is it be possible?

Comment: Take a look at [Native Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging)

Comment: You can exchange messages via sockets

Comment: I don't think he means to have a separate application running and communicating with it. I'd investigate if WebAssembly might suit you and be supported by a chrome extension